Vue3 copy outerHTML the click event not work
After copy the Click button, the copy Click button does not work.
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="container" ref="container">
      <button @click="handleClick">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div id="clip" ref="clip"></div>
    <button @click="copyContent">Copy Content</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const container = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
const clip = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)

function handleClick() {
  console.log('Clicked')
}

function copyContent() {
  if (container.value && clip.value) {
    // copy container outerHTML to clip innerHTML
    clip.value.innerHTML = container.value.outerHTML
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#container,
#clip {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>


What I tried
I fix the problem by adding a click event to copy click button.
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="container" ref="container">
      <button @click="handleClick">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div id="clip" ref="clip"></div>
    <button @click="copyContent">Copy Content</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const container = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
const clip = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)

function handleClick() {
  console.log('Clicked')
}

function copyContent() {
  if (container.value && clip.value) {
    // copy container outerHTML to clip innerHTML
    clip.value.innerHTML = container.value.outerHTML

    // fix the problem,is work
    const button = clip.value.querySelector('button')
    button!.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#container,
#clip {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>



What I am expecting
I wonder why vue3 is not working?
How can I use vue3 to solve the problem?

Vue does not like this mostly because you're trying to pass a Vue specific into some HTML, hence the DOM does not understand @click, ref etc. Using some querySelector, you could achieve something working indeed but you're not using Vue's state model anymore. Also, using outerHTML is actually quite dangerous IMO. Why not import or duplicate a VueJS component? That way it's safer and still will work well without injecting anything HTML. Also, it will be VueJS' way of doing things. You could even use Render Functions if you want to.

Vue's way to do anything is to work with VDOM and vnodes, so you just create a component that could return its slot and you use the slot a functional component:
See on Vue SFC Playground
<template>
  <div>
    <copy ref="$copy">
      <div id="container">
        <button @click="handleClick">Click me</button>
      </div>
    </copy>
    <div id="clip"><component :is="clip"/></div>
    <button @click="clip = () => $copy.getSlot()()">Copy Content</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Copy from './Copy.vue';

const clip = ref(null);
const $copy = ref();

function handleClick() {
  alert('click')
}

</script>

Copy.vue
<script setup>
import {useSlots} from 'vue';
const slots = useSlots();
defineExpose({
  getSlot(name = 'default'){ 
    return slots[name];
  } 
});
</script>

<template>
    <slot />
</template>

A functional approach:
See on Vue SFC Playground
<template>
  <div>
    <copy ref="$copy">
      <div id="container">
        <button @click="handleClick">Click me</button>
      </div>
    </copy>
    <div id="clip"><component :is="clip"/></div>
    <button @click="clip = () => $copy.getSlot()()">Copy Content</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, useSlots } from 'vue';

const Copy = {
  setup(_, {expose}) {
    const slots = useSlots();
    expose({getSlot: (name = 'default') => slots[name]});
    return () => slots.default();
  }
}

const clip = ref(null);
const $copy = ref();

function handleClick() {
  alert('click')
}

</script>

